# Offline data transaction processing capabilities in a context of poor internet connectivity

Tags: architecture, transaction

We have a core banking product developed with ASP.NET with C# using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 database. Product is hosted on a centralized server and works well at all locations (bank branches) where connectivity is good and stable.

We need to implement this solution at a region where connectivity is always an issue. Since it is a core-banking solution, there should not be any service lapse to the customer because of technical issues (viz., connectivity).

How to design the architecture for this and ensure that there is no transactional issues at any given point of time, and at the same time the centralized database contains the latest data from all branches?

Comment: Dont spend money on complicated software solutions to physical problems. Spend money fixing the connectivity.

Comment: @MattD: it may be not possible for a distant region or a large region with low population. Moreover, often, it doesn't depend on a private entity such as a bank, but on the authorities.

Comment: Thanks, Matt D, for the response.. Issue is with the 'spending money'... these banks (co-operative / societies) are have very low IT budget and will not be ready to spend.  Hence looking at an option, in case if it is possible to do any product related architectural changes (even if we consider only the critical transactional data).

Comment: How did these remote branches do business before computers?  The answer might help you come up with a good solution.  20 years ago nightly or weekly updates were the norm, as was low bandwidth and high latency (snail mail).

Comment: I think you should be wary of any queuing solution.  Basically, you branches will be giving out short term loans to customers whenever the connectivity to the central server is down.   You will have no idea whether the customer actually has that money in their account, because it is quite possible that a wire transfer came through and transferred the entire amount of the account to another party, while connectivity was disrupted.

Answer (score 1):

> How to design the architecture for this and ensure that there is no transactional issues at any given point of time, and at the same time the centralized database contains the latest data from all branches ?

**In short:** For the **serious** network connectivity issues between branches, it is **not possible** to have a *real-time solution*.

However, as a trade-off solution you may come up with nightly "data synchronization process" to central database/repository when network connectivity is stable. Drawback would be having a one day old information in central database. This is still a good solution for **reporting purposes**, however, for transactionl real-time solution it would not be sufficient.

As an additional food for thought, you may consider **distributed queuing approach**, as it will pile-up the requests to the main central server while the connectivity is lost or unstable. Once the network connectivity gets up, it will sent them in an order.

Overall, this requires a **trade-off**, rather than a working real-time solution for systems with connectivity problems.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to perhaps designing an overnight sync process, another option might be to use a distributed queuing approach.  That is, a queue at the branch site can queue up requests when the connectivity is down and these can be dequeued by the receiving system when connectivity is up. [This article](http://soapatterns.org/design_patterns/asynchronous_queuing) provides a pretty good overview.  There are a number of products/projects that support this capability - some possibilities include [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/), [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), and [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In this case, MSMQ is probably the most relevant.

From a front-end application standpoint, you need to design for this kind of asynchronous operation.  That is, the transaction needs to be considered complete by the application when it is placed on the queue and the assumption is that the queue is completely reliable.

As for the central location, it will always have the latest information available given network availability, subject to any lag introduced by the time it takes to process  the queued requests.  This is the best you can do in terms of recency of information if the network isn't reliable.

This kind of asynchronous queuing can be useful for a range of reasons beyond dealing with network connectivity and is a useful pattern to know.  For example, it can be used to effectively smooth load for a system that is servicing work from multiple requestors that don't require immediate response.  The "server" in this case doesn't need to be able to handle all of the load as it comes in so you can be more efficient from a resource utilization and not spec servers to handle "peak" loads while mostly sitting idle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it we meet your needs for real-time transactions, but you might want to look into using SQL Server Replication.

You could have a Web Server and SQL Server running at your remote location. The users there would connect to that instance. Using Replication, SQL Server would keep your data in sync between the two locations. If there was a drop in the connection, SQL Server would handle reconciling the data when the connection was available again.

I can't guarantee that this is the best solution for you without knowing all of your requirements or your access to SQL Server licenses. But it something you might want to investigate.

If it meets your needs, it would be a solution that wouldn't require any additional development.